# How to test files that use browserify-shim global's in Jest?

Tags: browserify, jestjs, browserify-shim

I'm downloading the google maps API v3 via a script tag, and I'm adding the dependency to my modules with the following (relevant) *package.json* configuration:

```
"browserify-shim": {
   "google": "global:google"
}
```

And I can add the dependency in my files with the following:

```
var google = require('google');
```

When I run my code in the browser, it works fine.
The problem is, when I run my tests with Jest, it tells me that it can't find the 'google' module:

```
Error: /src/app/assets/javascripts/__tests__/helpers-test.js: Cannot find module 'google' from '/src/app/assets/javascripts/__tests__'
```

**Note:**

This dependency is being required in the file that I'm testing, not the test itself. I find this confusing since I thought that Jest mocks all dependencies unless it is specified otherwise, but from what I can see, it first needs to correctly satisfy the dependencies before mocking.

Any ideas of what am I missing or what approach should I take?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to alias 'google' properly in your package.json, see [here](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#b-use-aliases).

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm not understanding about aliases. In the link you provided, a file is used in the aliases example, but the google maps api is loaded via a ascript tag (which I can't just download since it only downloads the missing components via more script tags).